# Is it true that $SX \simeq \mathbb{S}^1 \wedge X$?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, spheres

Let's define $SX = X \times I /(X \times \partial I \cup \lbrace x_0 \rbrace \times I)$ and the smash product $X \wedge Y = X \times Y /(\lbrace x_0 \rbrace \times Y \cup X \times \lbrace y_0 \rbrace)$.

I'd like to prove that $SX \simeq \mathbb{S}^1 \wedge X$ , is this true in general or depends on $X$? According to wikipedia on [reduced suspension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suspension_(topology)) this should be true.

So I took the following diagram :

$$X \times I \overset{f}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb{S}^1 \times X \overset{q}{\longrightarrow} S^1 \wedge X$$

Where $q$ is the projection and $f$ is given by $f(x,t) = (\cos(2\pi t),\sin(2\pi t),x)$. It's clear that $q \circ f$ is continuos, surjective, and called $p$ the projection $p : X \times I \longrightarrow SX$, that $q \circ f$ is costant on the fiber of $p$, so exists a continuos and bijective map $\tilde{f} : SX \longrightarrow \mathbb{S}^{1} \wedge X$.

What about finding an inverse? I should find a continuos map from $\mathbb{S}^1 \times X \longrightarrow X \times I$ first that works, but unable to find a simple one. Any easier methods or solution to prove that $\tilde{f}$ is an homeomorphism would be appreciated.

Edit : I'm not sure if this is true, here's why : It's a fact that *"the k-fold iterated reduced suspension of X is homeomorphic to the smash product of X and a k-sphere"* according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smash_product). So it should be true that $\Sigma X \simeq \mathbb{S}^{1} \wedge X$ and $SX \simeq \mathbb{S}^{1} \wedge X$. So it should be true in general that $SX \simeq \Sigma X$. If this is true I think excludes the homeomorphism, but feels necessary some hypothesis on $X$ to prove the latter as well, as $\lbrace x_0 \rbrace \times I$ being contractible

Answer (score 2):

It is impossible to obtain the continuous map $S^1\times X \to X\times I$ you desired. I think the easier way is to find the homeomorphism
$$
X\times I / X\times \partial I \cong X\times S^1/ X\times \{1\}.
$$
You can write the function explicitly, since in the quotient space, you can still use the coordinate system. We define a function $f$ as
$$
f(x,t) = (x,e^{2\pi i t}).
$$
You need to check that (1) this is well-defined, (2) this is continuous, (3) this is bijective, (4) inverse function is also continuous. Once you check them, you can pass this continuous map to the quotient,
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X\times I / X\times \partial I @>{\cong}>>  X\times S^1/ X\times \{1\}  \\
@VVV @VVV\\
SX @>{\cong}>> S^1 \wedge X
\end{CD}
$$

P.S. It looks safer to assume that $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff. See comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try the step by step. Why is it impossible to find such a map?

Comment: @jacopoburelli Along the map $X\times I \to X\times S^1$, the coordinate of $X$ is fixed, so in order to obtain the inverse $X\times S^1 \to X\times I$, one must have $S^1 \to I$, which is simply the composition $S^1 \to X\times S^1 \to X\times I \to I$. One can check that this is the inverse of $I \to S^1$. This means $S^1$ and $I$ are homeomorphic, which is definitely not true.

Comment: What changes? In order to find the inverse of the function you wrote I have to find a function from $X \times S^1 /\left(X \times 1\right)$ to $X \times I / X \times \partial I$. The fact that is defined from the quotient, gives the possibility denied to the map $S^1 \longrightarrow I$ I was searching?

Comment: Yes because $S^1$ is homeomorphic to $I/\partial I$.

Comment: On p.333 of Rotman the result is true if $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff while here, seems true in general, what's wrong?

Comment: @jacopoburelli I guess there might be a counterexample of the Lemma 8.9 when $Z$ is not locally compact Hausdorff. I am not aware of such example, so I must assume that $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff in my answer.

Comment: Where did you use locally compact to show the homeomorphism?

Comment: I think you need the homeomoprhism $X\times I/\{x_0\}\times \partial I \to X\times S^1 / \{x_0\}\times \{1\}$ to prove the first equation. It seems being locally compact Hausdorff is needed to prove that this is an homeomoprhism.